# Generating My Angular Project Release Notes with Standard Version

Tags: github, angular-cli, release-management, changelog

I created an Angular project using `angular-cli` and pushed it to GitHub. I then created a new branch and updated packages, installed `standard-version` and ran `npm run release -- --first-release` as instructed. I then pushed the whole into a new branch on GitHub, created a pull request, squashed and merged onto `master`, pulled back into local `master`, and ran `standard-version` again finally followed by `git push --follow-tags origin master`. Here's the state on GitHub:

[image]

1. All notes that I wrote in the pull request body are not visible in the changelog file, and they are obviously not in the `chore(release)` generated by `standard-version`. Why?
2. They are also not written within the `Releases` tabs at all, even though I can see the released tags there.
3. Should I have made the version 1.0.0 in `packages.json` before starting in order to adhere to semantic versioning?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're not doing anything wrong. `chore` doesn't show up in `CHANGELOG.md` (see: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version/issues/135)
2. To have release notes uploaded, you will to use something like https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-github-releaser
3. It's up to you where to start. Generally, when labeled `0.x`, the project is still unstable and will go through vast API changes. When the project becomes stable, bump the major to `1.x` and adhere to semver.

Comment: Thank you, but then how about all my commits before chore release, which you can see up there in the comment before. They didn’t show up in the change log file either.

Comment: Oh, the previous pull request was also titled "chore: ..." so then its body would also be ignored?

Comment: Correct. You'll need to use `feat`, `fix`, `refactor`, etc for them to show up in the file. All bodies are ignored when generating the `CHANGELOG.md`. You'll only see the title, a link to the commit, the pr it came from, and any breaking changes (in it's own section at the end of the version release).